Origen del significado de "soplagaitas"
La definición de soplagaitas es: Persona tonta o estúpida.
¿Como se ha llegado a eso?
Es decir, ¿qué relación tiene con la gaita, un instrumento musical?

Les encanta soplar las gaitas, como a vos.

La palabra "soplagaitas" es una expresión coloquial que se utiliza en España para referirse a una persona que habla mucho y sin sentido, o que es molesta y fastidiosa.
Literalmente, "soplagaitas" se traduce como "soplador de gaitas", donde "gaita" es un instrumento musical de viento.
La idea es que alguien que sopla una gaita produce un sonido continuo y a veces irritante, lo cual se asocia metafóricamente con alguien que habla demasiado sin aportar nada útil.
El origen de esta expresión es incierto, pero se cree que proviene de la comparación con el sonido persistente y a veces molesto de la gaita. Es una forma despectiva de referirse a alguien que no deja de hablar o que es considerado un charlatán.

